# Is using a string from url a possible security risk?

Tags: javascript, security

My simplified code:

```
var key = window.location.hash;

someObject[key]();
```

Is there any chance that the attacker could execute somehow his code ?

Comment: is there any interaction with the server ? If not, all he could execute would be on his own machine...

Comment: Attacker can do anything he wants, JS is running on **his** machine. What you can do is to keep your server-side script safe so that no attacks can cause you any risk!

Comment: I highly doubt fhat this can be exploited. Still, if you don't want to take the risk, just set up a whitelist of allowed values for `key`

Comment: @LightStyle: if that were true, XSS would not be an issue

Comment: @NiklasB.: XSS always involves a server that incorrectly sends "live" content to the client. If you cut the server part out there would be no XSS.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for answering 5 seconds before me :P

Comment: @Jon: It can also work through hash fragments, which is a pure client-side concept

Comment: @NiklasB.: Granted. But really, taking the fragment and embedding it in HTML or evaling it is such a colossally stupid thing to do that it did not even cross my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snipplet should be *"Save"*, but it depence, on what functions are contained in the *someObject* Object, and what the implications of an attack would be XSS would.

Just think about, what is the worst thing that could happen, if someone alters the hash value an executes an other function. Or what would happen, if someone sends an link with a special hash value to someone else. 
If The Answer is, nothing you should be save.

I hope this helps